# can I file a small claims court to get a wire transfer reversed due to fraud?

Tags: fraud

Wired $7,175 to a fraudulent website to TCF bank. It's been 7 months now and neither bank will help me.

Comment: Whom do you want to sue?

Comment: Really, the only entity you can sue here is the owner of the fraudulent website. Its generally not the responsibility of the banks to second guess who you are sending money to. Small claims courts in the US typically require that the defendant reside in the same county as the court. Do you know who the owner of the web site is, whether they live in the same county as you?

Answer (score 3):

No. A lawsuit in small claims court won't reverse the wire transfer. At best, it will get you a judgment against whoever committed fraud. Of course, you will have to identify and serve whoever committed fraud and even if you get a judgment, you will have to enforce it.